# jQTouch not displaying the iPhone and Arrows

Tags: jqtouch

My jQTouch application when run does not show any iPhone or anything. I though those images are in the themes folder but nothing is there. Also, when the links appear they do not display arrows. Is this project even alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your track record here on SO, you seem to have way more dev experience than me... but I'll give this a shot.

1) Going off the files included with the download, make sure you're including these files from the **jqtouch** folder: *jqtouch.css, jqtouch.js, jquery.1.3.2.min.js*

2) There should be two subfolders in the themes folder. If what you're after is more of an apple iPhone look and feel, from the **themes/apple/** folder, make sure to include *theme.css*

3) Each theme's images live inside an img folder, which should contain all the button graphics. Are you not seeing these folders in the .zip file you downloaded from [jqtouch.com](http://www.jqtouch.com/)?

4) In the .zip file from the site, there should be several examples that mirror the [online demo page](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/). Specifically, you can look at the *index.html* page located at **demos/main/**

If you're able to share your code, it might be easier to try to diagnose what the specific problem is. From what I can gather, everything functions but the overall look and feel is missing, no buttons/styles, etc. Is this correct?

The project is still very much alive. While not as populated as StackOverflow, the [jQTouch Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jqtouch) is still active.

Comment: Thanks! i have already added the required css and js files. There is no apple folder inside the themes folder. but there is a base folder inside the themes folder which is weird. Nope I do not see any img folder. I downloaded the beta version which is the latest. I think they messed up the package.

Comment: weird downloaded again and now the apple folder is there! thanks